# Chain rule for distributional derivative

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $V \subset H \subset V^*$ be a Gelfand triple (eg. $H^1 \subset L^2 \subset H^{-1}$).

Let $u \in L^2(0,T;V)$ have a distributional derivative $u' \in L^2(0,T;V^*)$. So $\int_0^T u(t)\varphi'(t) = -\int_0^T u'(t)\varphi(t)$ holds for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(0,T)$ as an equality in $V^*$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with $f'$ bounded.

Suppose $u' \in L^2(0,T;L^2)$; then the chain rule formula for the weak derivative $(f(u))' = f'(u)u' \in L^2(0,T;L^2)$ makes sense.

But if $u' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ only, how to make sense of $(f(u))'$? Is it right to define the derivative as $$\langle (f(u))', v \rangle := \langle u', f'(u)v \rangle$$
**if** for all $v \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$, $f'(u)v \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$?

Where may I find more details about this sort of thing? I'd like to avoid BV spaces and measures because this is simpler. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the question being asked makes sense. You are treating $u$ as an $L^2$ valued function, then you **cannot** plug $u$ into $f$, which has domain $\mathbb{R}$. Perhaps you meant to think about $u$ as a space-time function, and $f$ as really acting on the final output. But then it is not compatible with the form of the chain rule you are suggesting. (In fact, if the spatial domain is non-compact, and $f(0) \neq 0$, you don't even have $f(u)$ is an element of $L^2(0,T;L^2)$.) So I think the first thing is to for you to think about and specify what exactly is this object $f(u)$.

Answer (score 0):

For the $H^1 \subset L^2 \subset H^{-1}$ case.

Let $K_\epsilon$ be a mollifier then for $u\in L^2(0,T;L^2)$ we have that $u_\epsilon = K_\epsilon\ast u$ is actually smooth. In fact, $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} u_\epsilon$ converges to $u$ in $L^p_{loc}$ for all $p\in [1,\infty)$. Since $f$ is differentiable, then it is continuous. So, we have the $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} f(u_\epsilon) = f(u)$ in the same spaces as before.

Consider the following,
\begin{align*}
 \langle v',f(u_\epsilon)\rangle 
&= -\langle v, f'(u_\epsilon) u_\epsilon' \rangle \\
&= -\langle v,f'(u) u_\epsilon' \rangle + \langle v,\left[f'(u) - f'(u_\epsilon)\right] u_\epsilon'\rangle
\end{align*}
A useful fact to use is that since $f$ has bounded derivative then $f$ is Lipshitz. Using this fact and taking $\epsilon$ to zero gives you what you want.

Comment: Do you mean the brackets to be in space or space-time? I'm trying to understand the meaning of the displayed equation ...

Comment: It should only be space, no? I meant it as mathias did in his question and I thought he had taken it to only be a space integral. The idea is to use a smoothing argument and take limits.

Comment: If the brackets are in space, then it seems the full time derivative is missing ..

Comment: Shouldn't the second bracket read  $\langle v,f'(u_\epsilon)u'_\epsilon \rangle$?

Comment: Yes, I am missing a $'$ in the second bracket. That is a typo. Your questions are fair and now I am thoroughly confused about what I have. I am considering what I've written.

Comment: OK, I now think that the angled brackets refer to space-time integration (i.e. $\langle u,v\rangle = \int_0^T \int_{\mathbb{R}} uv$). I think what I wrote above still works. You may just need to smooth everything out in space-time now instead of just space.

Comment: Do you know of a good reference for smoothing properties of vectorial Lp spaces?

Comment: What is a vectoral $L^p$ space? I'm not familiar with this terminology. Do you mean functions whose image is in a vector space?

Comment: @k3thomps Thanks for answer. When I was trying to write with the duality pairing is this. If  $(f(u))' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ is a weak derivative, then it seems natural to me that *its action* (recall that $(f(u))'$ is an element of the dual space to $L^2(0,T;H^1)$) should be $$\langle (f(u))', v\rangle_{L^2(0,T;H^{-1}), L^2(0,T;H^1)} = \langle u', f'(u)v \rangle_{L^2(0,T;H^{-1}), L^2(0,T;H^1)}$$ **if** $f'(u)v \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$. This is what I would expect because we know what $u'$ is. But whether this is how it should be is what I am not sure about.

Comment: Oh, the above argument shows that what you suggest is true. I showed that $f(u)' = f'(u) u'$. You can then plug this into the dual pairing and rearrange to get exactly the quantity you want.

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand $v'$ because $v$ is just in $L^2(0,T;H^1)$.

Comment: I am actually using that $v$ is smooth with compact support. You can then use density of $C_0^\infty$ to extend the above identity to $L^2(0,T;H^1)$.

Comment: -1, the second addend at the RHS doesn't go to $0$ if $f$ is not $C^1$. The answer to OP's question is still positive though. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430332/chain-rule-in-sobolev-space

Comment: $C^1$ functions with bounded first derivatives are dense in the space of differentiable functions with bounded derivative. You can approximate $f$ using $f_\eta \in C^1$ with $f_\eta \rightarrow f$, use the argument above to show that it's true for all $\eta > 0$, and take $\eta \rightarrow 0$ to re-coupe the above for all differentiable functions with bounded derivative.

Comment: @No-one: are you sure the proof of the linked MO question applies here? At the level the OP is asking about I don't even believe $f(u)$ makes sense as an $L^2$ function....