# Chain rule in Sobolev space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, schwartz-distributions

In the theory of Sobolev space, we have the following chain rule:

- For a uniformly Lipschitz  function $F : \mathbf{R}\to \mathbf{R}$ such that $F(0)=0$,
  and $u\in W^{1,1}(\mathbf{R}^n)$, then we have the following chain rule:
  $\partial_j F(u)=F'(u)\circ \partial_ju$.

But how to define the function $F'(u)$? It seems that we can't define $F'(u(.))$ a.e., and it may be not a measurable function.

Comment: Does the fact that Lipschitz functions are differentiable a.e. not help you here?

Comment: @ Daniel Shapero,  if $A$ is a null set in R, the set $u^{-1}(A)$ maybe not be a null set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main difficulty in the proof of the rule is to prove that $\nabla u=0$ a.e. on the set $u^{-1}(\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is the set where $F$ is not differentiable; and where $\nabla u=0$ one defines the product $F'(u)\nabla u$ to be 0, irrespective of the fact that $F'(u)$ is defined or not a such points. See e.g. Leoni, Morini: JEMS 9 pp 219-252

Comment: Also relevant in this context (though in the setting of vector-valued spaces): [Arendt and Kreuter](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1398.46026)